# How to come out of if tag of JSTL , like using break in C if loop.

Tags: jstl

I am using Jstl if tag to check condition I would like to know ,How to come out of if tag of JSTL , like using break in C if loop.

Comment: There is no such thing as an if loop.

Comment: Maybe the OP means `<c:forEach>` instead of `<c:if>`.  @Sachin can you clarify?

Comment: it's nested if else  in JSTL(assuming we have nested ifelse )

Comment: In C, `break` only breaks out of loops.  It will break out of `if` statements only if the `if` statement is in a loop.  Is that the case you are thinking about?

Comment: No not in for loop it's in nested if loop

Answer (score 1):

```
The simplest way to break out of a loop is to use a boolean variable.

example:
<c:set var="conditionVariable" value ="true"/>
<c:forEach ..>
<c:if test="${conditionVariable eq 'true'}>

<!-- code that should be execute --!>



<c:if> - your condition
<c:set var="conditionVariable" value="false"/>
</c:if>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own break tag, as shown [here](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/06/21/break-a-foreach-loop-using-jstl/).

You can also try setting the loop status variable to the index of the last element in the collection (but I have never tried this).